# Make Bootstrap-Vue modal draggable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

I'm using bootstrap-vue modals in a project and wan't them to be draggable.

I googled for this, but I'm fairly new to webdevelopment so I'm a bit overwelmed with the solutions for bootstrap without vue.

I think example-code is not necessary as I'm using standard bootstrap-vue modals. Tell me if i'm wrong.

Could you provide some examples for bootsrap-vue or explain how to use the bootstrap-only solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

BootstrapVue `<b-modal>` uses Bootstrap v4.x CSS/SCSS styling to position the modals.

The styling uses absolute positioning for the viewport, and auto-left/right margins to center the modal horizontally and a top margin to position the modal partially down from the top of the page.

So unfortunately, out of the box, you can't position them absolutely in the viewport.

You would need to change the positioning of the modal dialog sub-container to absolute and control the left/top position based on dragging.  This is not an overly easy task. You would need to create your own header (using the scoped slot for the header), and add event listeners for click/drag and if dragging, then switch the position of the `.modal-dialog` container to absolute, and then compute the left/top coordinates and used traditional DOM style adjustments to that element.

Comment: Thanks. I switched to non Bootstrap-Modals and now it's working.

Comment: @Eardy Out of interest, what did you use?